# What's the minimum number of keystrokes needed to type n asterisks?

Tags: optimization, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you're editing a plain txt file and need to input a line of $n$ asterisk characters. You could press the <kbd>*</kbd> key $n$ times (assuming you have a numpad with a dedicated <kbd>*</kbd> key) but there is certainly a faster way by using the select-all/copy/paste keyboard shortcuts. For example if $n = 80$ you can type the asterisks with these eighteen keystrokes:

<kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

For a particular $n$ is there is a way to determine the *minimum* number of keystrokes necessary?

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852616/167197), the opposite question in a sense, that deserves more attention.

Comment: There certainly is a way to determine the minimum number of keystrokes, namely by searching through all sequences of length at most $n$ but it clearly isn't computationally feasible except for very small $n$. Clearly you can do pretty well by mimicking the steps in the recursive calculation of $\log_2 n$ (integer logarithm). Whether that is optimal in all cases, I don't know.

Comment: You might need the delete key as well

Comment: @Empy2 Good point. I wonder how much tougher of a question this is allowing for the delete/backspace key vs not?

Comment: 2 key press (not key stroke) - fireup notepad, press `Shift` and `*` w/o releasing them...

Comment: Using base 5 you need about $10\log_5n$ keystrokes.  
Eight keystrokes to quintuple, and up to two deletes or asterisk per digit.

Comment: Hint:  Think exponents.  $*$ gives you one $*$ ans $ctrl, a, c, v$ well double what you've got.  So in $1 + 4k$ keystrokes you can get $2^k$ $*$.   If $n \ne 2^k$ we can: find $2$ so that $2^{k} < n < 2^{k+1}$; figure $m=\min(n-2^k,2^{k+1}-n +4)$. The either add or subtract asterisks but press $*$ or $del$ $m$ times.

Comment: @fleablood Based on [the answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4211676/167197), that won't get you the *minimum* most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an $O(n^{1.5})$ time solution assuming you are only allowed to use *, ctrl, a,c,v, and that further you're only allowed to use them to

1. print *
2. copy what you have already and paste it k times.

(not sure if there are other clever key combinations with these keys.)

Algorithm:

Assume inductively that you know an optimal way to produce, $0, 1, ..., n-1$ *'s. Call these strings of keystrokes $b_0, \ldots, b_{n-1}$.

Now, we just try each possibility.

First we consider just taking the solution $b_{n-1}$ and typing another *.  This takes $l(b_{n-1}) + 1$ keystrokes, where $l(b_{i})$ means the number of keystrokes in solution $b_i$.

Then, for each divisor $d>1$ of $n$, we consider trying: $b_n$ + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>...<kbd>v</kbd> with $n/d$ v's.  This takes $l(b_n) + 3 + n/d$ keystrokes.  This is assuming that we needed to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>; if there was a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> already active, we only need $l(b_n) + 2 + n/d$ keystrokes. (We need to release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to write *, at least on my keyboard...).

Then, we take the optimal of all these possibilities. We can use trial division for this, and so at most $\sqrt{n}$ steps are taken. Implementing this in Python I get $l(b_{80}) = 18$ as you do.

As the comments mention, if you are allowed to delete, we can optimize further, but this would force considering $b_k$ for $k > n$ which wouldn't be allowed under our inductive assumption, and so this recursive algorithm would not seem to be easily adapted.

edit:

The most efficient strings I found for $n \leq 20$ are

```
0 
1 *
2 * *
3 * * *
4 * * * *
5 * * * * *
6 * * * * * *
7 * * * * * * *
8 * * * * * * * *
9 * * * ctrl a c v v v
10 * * ctrl a c v v v v v
11 * * ctrl a c v v v v v *
12 * * * ctrl a c v v v v
13 * * * ctrl a c v v v v *
14 * * ctrl a c v v v v v v v
15 * * * ctrl a c v v v v v
16 * * * * ctrl a c v v v v
17 * * * * ctrl a c v v v v *
18 * * * ctrl a c v v v v v v
19 * * * ctrl a c v v v v v v *
20 * * * * ctrl a c v v v v v
```

and the values of $l(b_n)$ for $0 \leq n \leq 100$ are

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 11, 12, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 16, 17, 16, 17, 18, 16, 17, 18, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 17, 18, 18, 19, 20, 21, 17, 18, 19, 18, 17, 18, 19, 20, 19, 20, 19, 20, 18, 19, 20, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 18, 19, 20, 21, 19, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 21, 19, 20, 21, 22, 19
```

As we might expect, it exhibits logarithmic growth:[image]

Comment: I included 'delete' by comparing Best(n) with Best(n+1), and redoing the whole calculation over and over, up to n=15000, until it stabilized, which was about five iterations.  I got an average improvement of 0.726 keystrokes.  The first improvement was for 23, while 5039 got an improvement of 7 keystrokes.

Comment: @Empy2 Cool. I had something in mind like that too, but didn't get around to implementing it.